# Working with Twig and PHPMailer

Tags: php, html, css, twig, phpmailer

I am developing a web that work with Twig and PHPMailer. When the system send a email, I want that email's body to be in HTML. I must show data in email's body. I have the file personal.php that pass data to file personal.html by Twig

```
$twig->display('Personal.html',array(
    "text" => $text,
    "lenguaje" => substr($lang, 0, 2)
    ));
```

How I do to pass the HTML file with Twig?. When I pass data I do

```
$body = '<div>
            <p>'.$this->text['pass_recov_body'].'</p>
            <p><strong>'.$this->text['date_user'].'</strong></p>
            <p><strong>'.$this->text['user'].': </strong>'. $data['txtRecEmail'] . '</p>
            <p><strong>'.$this->text['password'].': </strong>'. $data['txtUsrPass'] . '</p>
        </div>
    ';


    $this->msgHTML($body);
```

but now I want pass a HTML file with CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use render() instead of display()

```
$this->msgHTML($twig->render('Personal.html',array(
    "text" => $text,
    "lenguaje" => substr($lang, 0, 2)
)));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also attach the rendered html as a file if you do something like

```
// attach rendered html as file with timestamp
$renderedform = $twig->render('Personal.html',array(
    "text" => $text,
    "lenguaje" => substr($lang, 0, 2)
));
$mail->AddStringAttachment( 
    $renderedform, 
    'AttachmentFileName_'. time() .'.html', 
    'base64', 
    'text/html'
);
```