# Dynamically created anchor tags are not displaying as a link in email template when received at client end

Tags: symfony, email, templates, hyperlink, phpmailer

I am creating a link for an email template to approve some order.

```
$approvalLink = "<a href='" . $url . "/Request/Approval/code/" . $Code . "'>Approve</a>";
```

This link works fine most of the time but sometimes it displays as a string because an unintended space is added between "<" and "a". As a result of this link appears to be a string. this is how link looks like in the email:

```
< a href='blahblah'>Approve</a>
```

What can be the possible reason for this space and how can I fix it?

I am using PHP, symfony and phpmailer class to send emails.

Comment: It is possible that the character encoding in some part of the process results not supported by the ending client? The HTML segment is hardcoded (or stored somewhere) and is correctly encoded?

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion would be to use the $approvalLink variable this way, should be safer and may fix hidden chars or encoding problems:

```
$approvalLink = sprintf('<a href="%s/Request/Approval/code/%s">Approve</a>', $url, $Code);
```

Second suggestion would be to use Twig to build the email body, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23738741/working-with-twig-and-phpmailer).

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens because SMTP adds a line break where line is greater than 998 characters. To overcome this issue we need to add new line manually or base64 encode the email contents.

Reference and solution here:

[Max line length in mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794698/max-line-length-in-mail)

[PHP mail function randomly adds a space to message text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999908/php-mail-function-randomly-adds-a-space-to-message-text/22052966)